# How to correctly encode URL?

Tags: php, url

I want to encode like what browser did,

For example. `https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%2520你好`

Should be encoded as `https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%2520%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD`

I am using the following regex to encode URI without like `rawurlencode` encode `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%2520你好';
echo preg_replace_callback("{[^0-9a-z_.!~*'();,/?:@&=+$#]}i", function ($m) {
    return sprintf('%%%02X', ord($m[0]));
}, $url);
```

But this will return `https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%252520%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD` which has an extra `25`.

How can I correctly encode the URL that user inputed without modifying original address?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **urlencode** for this purpose. It will encode `%2520你好` into `%252520%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD` . Use the code below.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%2520'.urlencode("你好").'';
echo $url;
?>
```

I think this will give you your desired url

Comment: That's the problem, note that is `q=%2520%` not `?q=%252520%`

Comment: also, `urlencode` encode `&` to `%26`, so will break all query strings, that's why I need to exclude `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`

Comment: Its not giving an extra 25. Encoding this 你好 gives 2520%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD. %25 means %. You are thinking that it is putting one extra 25 but it doesn't

Comment: But if you type that URL in browser, the translated URL have no extra 25

Comment: hmm, can this called answer? how about i want a function to encode any URL typed

Comment: @user3896501 Considering the question, it certainly does look like an answer. You never specified wanting a generic function to use anywhere. This is a working replacement on the example code you provided of your current situation. To make this into a function just look up functions on php.net.